# How can I modify React build to give me multiple JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build

I have a multi-page application that doesn't use Node. It has a bunch of HTML and JavaScript files. I want to render React components in the application, which I found I am able to do with `ReactDOM.render`.

However, I am building out the React components separately in a project made with `npx create-react-app`. I can use `npm run build` which gives me a `main.js` file that contains a production ready version of all my components.

I can add this `main.js` file into my HTML files with a script tag to have my components render in my multi-page application.

However, the problem is that I notice when I `run npm build`, I get one `main.js` file that contains everything. This is not good because the app will run too slow if I have to load all of my React components in `main.js` file every time I go to a new page.

Instead, I am looking to only load the specific components I need for a page.

Example:

Let's say I had a test1 component and a test2 component.
Page1 has a script to use test1, so I only want to load test1 on Page1.
Page2 has a script to use test2, so I only want to load test2 on Page2.
Therefore, I need a `test1.js` file and a `test2.js` file after `npm run build`

How would I do this?

Comment: You haven't even told us what the build script _is_, so it's going to be very hard to say. CRA?

Comment: the default npm run build that comes with react

Comment: That's not a thing. Do you mean from react-_scripts_, Create React App? Please [edit] to provide the context. But note if it is CRA you're going to have to be prepared to eject and do a fair bit of work.

Comment: Fundamentally you're using the wrong tool for the job. CRA (at least the default templates) is for creating React _apps_, an SPA, not a component library.

Comment: Okay I've edited my original post. Yes it is from the react-scripts from create react app. Once I eject I see that there is a build script, but how would I edit it to provide the multiple js files?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a use case for [Code Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html).

If you want to split per-page with React Router you can do the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Home = React.lazy(() => import("./Home"));
const Contact = React.lazy(() => import("./Contact"));

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This should generate multiple JS files for different components (e.g. pages) when used with some standard build tools like [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/).